# Why does scanf("%i",a) not take binary like 0b101?

Tags: c

I'm confused about the binary expression like `0b10101`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
  int a,b;
  b = 0b101;
  scanf("%i",&a);
  printf("the value of a is %d\n", a);
  printf("the value of b is %d\n", b);
}
```

when I type `0b101`,

the output gives me

```
the value of a is 0;
the value of b is 5;
```

instead of two 5's as it should be.

Is there any way to make `scanf` take binary input?

Comment: Which extended dialect of C are you using?  That is not standard C.  Standard C does not recognize 0b for binary literals.

Comment: if you need you can read the input as string and parse it yourself

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Standard C has no specific notation prefix for representing binary notation. Only decimal, octal and hexadecimal are supported. Although the `0b` prefix was proposed for C99 (and rejected), so it is probably not unusual to see it implemented in some compilers.

Even if you saw `0b` prefix supported by some specific C implementation as an extension (GCC?), it would be rather surprising see it recognized by `scanf`'s `%i` format specifier, since it would break compatibility with standard implementations. The latter are required to stop reading at `b`.

Judging by your test results though it appears that the compiler supports `0b...` integral literals, while the standard library knows nothing about them. Maybe the documentation for that library has something to say about it, like some extended non-standard format specifier/flag for `scanf` that makes it recognize `0b...` prefixes. I don't see it in GCC docs though.

Comment: Here is a link to [Binary Constants](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-5.3.0/gcc/Binary-constants.html#Binary-constants) GCC Extension